# How to merge selected items in ListBox into one in vb .NET?

Tags: vb.net

How can I merge selected items in ListBox into one?

for example, I have a listbox that includes 6 items:

```
item1
item2
item3
item4
item5
item6
```

and I want to pick any item I like and combine them, for example I like to select item3 and item5 and result:

```
item1
item2
item3 & item5
item4
item6
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way:

```vb
Dim selectedItems As New List(Of String)
For Each item As String In Listbox1.SelectedItems 
    selectedItems.Add(item)
Next

Dim newItems As New List(Of String)
Dim unifiedItem As Nullable(Of Integer) = Nothing

For Each item As String In Listbox1.Items
    If Not selectedItems.Contains(item) Then
        newItems.Add(item)
    Else
        If unifiedItem Is Nothing Then
            unifiedItem = newItems.Count
            newItems.Add(item)
        Else
            newItems(unifiedItem) &= " & " & item
        End If
    End If
Next

ListBox1.Items.Clear()
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(newItems.ToArray)
```

Comment: WOW this is exactly what I was looking for. This code is excellent. This cod works like a charm. Thanks a million Dear Yair Maron for help.

Comment: Gladly, Happy to help